# Completeness in metric spaces is somewhat a 'universal' property

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Given a metric space $X$ , show that :

$X$ is complete $\iff$ For every complete metric space $Y$ and continuous $f:X\rightarrow Y$ : $f$ maps Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Take any noncomplete metric space $X$, take $Y$ its completion, and $f : X \rightarrow Y$ the isometric embedding. Then $f$ maps Cauchy sequences to Cauchy-sequences... So, the claim is false.

Comment: @Plop But does it makes a difference that the right-hand side says for *every* complete metric space $Y$?  Your example doesn't satisfy the conditions on the right-hand side of the implication, because it's only *one* such $Y$.

Comment: Sure... No more math for today for me...

Comment: Assume there is a point $x_0$ in the completion $Y$ of $X$ and not in $X$. Consider $x \longmapsto d_Y(x,x_0)$.

Comment: Can we prove it without using completions? This problem is asked with no prior knowledge about completions, we can just use the complete $\mathbb{R} $ instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is complete, and if $Y$ is a metric space and $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous map, let $(x_n)_{n}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $X$. Then it is convergent. So the sequence $(f(x_n))_{n}$ is also convergent, and so it is Cauchy.

For the other direction, I use an idea from Mindlack's comment.

Let $X$ be a metric space. Let $(x_n)_{n}$ be a Cauchy sequence, and assume it doesn't have a limit. Consider the completion of $X$, denoted by $\overline{X}$, and the canonical isometric embedding $j : X \rightarrow \overline{X}$. Let $x_\infty \in \overline{X}$ be the limit of $(j(x_n))_n$.

Let $g : x \mapsto d_{\overline{X}}(x_\infty,x)$. It is a continuous function, and it is everywhere non-zero, by assumption. So $f := x \mapsto g(x)^{-1}$ is continuous on $X$.

Now, $(f(x_n))_n$ goes to infinity, and is Cauchy by assumption. This is a contradiction. So $(x_n)_n$ is convergent.

Comment: However I am still thinking for a proof without using completions, assuming we don't know each metric space has a completion.